# Android: Spinner text alignment to the right but not centered

Tags: android, layout, arabic

I finished the English version of my application and now I am working on the Arabic localization. Arabic is a right-to-left language, so I need to adjust a lot of things in my layout, including my spinner display.

I used the same approach mentioned here [Android - Text is Pushed to the Left in a Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755506/text-is-pushed-to-the-left-in-a-spinner-android) but I set the gravity to right.

Here is my spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Changed my code from

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

to this

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
```

I want my spinner to look like my old English spinner found below,

[image: English spinner]

But it currently looks like this,

[image: Arabic spinner]

How can I restore the following:

1. The radio button
2. The bigger text size
3. I want it to the right as shown but centered between the two dividers.

NOTE The Arabic webservices aren't finished yet, that's why the data in the image is still in English.

**UPDATE**

After trying Adil Soomro's suggestion, I get the following,

[image: Spinner semi-desired]

There is no radiobutton and there is a considerable space between the border and the first letter.

**UPDATE**

After Adil Soomro's edit, I now have the following,

[image: Spinner Arabic Fixed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `CheckedTextView`, it will solve your all 3 problems.

You will place a layout xml something like this:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Comment: when it is CheckedTextView this method doesn't work anymore :-| Although with general TextView it is Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

To

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
```