# Android: Spinner selection aligned to the left

Tags: android, layout, spinner, arabic, gravity

I finished the English version of my application and now I am working on the Arabic localization. Arabic is a right-to-left language, so I need to adjust a lot of things in my layout, including my spinner display.

When I choose an item from the spinner selection menu, I see the following,

[image: Spinner selection]

As you can see "Allergy" is aligned to the left and on top of the spinner arrow. I need it to be aligned to the right.

**NOTE** The Arabic webservices aren't finished yet, that's why the data in the image is still in English.

**EDIT**

```
Spinner mSpecialtySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.specialty_appointment_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<Specialty> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Specialty>(AppointmentReservationActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, specialities);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        mSpecialtySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can have another layout for Spinner and pass it to `ArrayAdapter's` constructor.

make an xml file naming `spinner_layout.xml` in layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip" 
    android:gravity="right"
     />
```

and now pass it in `ArrayAdapter's` constructor like this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,conversionsadd);
```

Please remember:

what we have provided as `R.layout.spinner_layout` in `ArrayAdapter` constructor is layout of Spinner. and what we will provide as `setDropdownView()` is Spinner item (drop down item).

You can have a look at my another relative answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921087/593709)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a new spinner dropdown layout and set `android:gravity="right"` on the appropriate widget.

Call it with:

```
yourSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.right_aligned_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you could please check my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341613/android-spinner-text-alignment-to-the-right-but-not-centered you will see that I am using android:gravity="right|center_vertical" but it's only being applied to the drop down view and not the unclicked spinner view. Any ideas?