# Android: Align spinner text

Tags: android

I am trying to align spinner text to left but gravity and textAlingment attributes don`t help in it. How can I put the text to center_vertical|right?

That`s my spinner:

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sPaymentFreq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/payment_freq"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:prompt="@string/choose_payment_freq" />
```

Or there is no way to do playing with attributes only? I just read that some guys achieve the result making custom spinner but I just need so small change.

Comment: Take at look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341613/android-spinner-text-alignment-to-the-right-but-not-centered