# Style not appyling on Spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-styles

[image]

In this app, I want to Center item of Spinner. I have tried `android:gravity="center"`, but it is not working? and I have to add small image on spinner. how I do this. please guide me.

in `res/layout` **spinner_layout.xml**

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">`
      <Spinner
               android:id="@+id/spinner1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="55dp" 
               android:prompt="@string/spinner_promt"
              style="@style/spinnerStyleView"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
```

style in `**style.xml**`

```
        <style name="spinnerStyleView">
              <item name="android:background"> @drawable/notetvbg</item>
              <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
           </style>`
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299194/how-to-change-the-text-background-color-of-a-opened-spinner-on-android/15299268#15299268

Comment: not working... I have to make spinner item in center of spinner itself and also want to add small image/icon before the text @Pragnani

Comment: For the textview in the above answer, set gravity =center to achieve this

Comment: but I didn't use `textview` here, so how I achieve this. @Pragnani

Comment: Then try @Girishu answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Text is Pushed to the Left in a Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755506/android-text-is-pushed-to-the-left-in-a-spinner)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to make style spinner..

> drawable/slim_spinner_normal.9.png

[image]

> drawable/slim_spinner_pressed.9.png

[image]

> drawable/spinner_back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
             <item android:state_pressed="true"
                   android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_pressed" />
             <item android:drawable="@drawable/slim_spinner_normal" />
        </selector>
```

> layout/main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_TAG_FRAME"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_back.xml" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Additional skins

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you tell me how I do spinner item to center..@XEENA

Comment: I have mentioned above.. that android:gravity="center" not setting spinner text to center. is there any other way to do this. @XEENA