# Setting the text to be in the center works for one spinner, but not for other

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, spinner

In my application I've got 3 spinners - one on the top, which when used provides the user with 2 more aligned below it.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755506/text-is-pushed-to-the-left-in-a-spinner-android) where I found the answer I was looking for, but only half-way.. Now the two supplementary spinners have their text shown in the center, but the first one - no.

Looking at the .xml for the spinners I can see only one difference regarding to centering and it is that the two supplementary ones have the `android:layout_gravity="center"` attribute, which for some reason is not applicable to the first spinner. Why is this so? Could this be the reason? By not applicable I mean it is not in the properties for the spinner in the design view and when I add it manually in the .xml nothing changes.

So ideally the answer which I am looking for is **why the 2 supplementary spinners have their text centered, but the first one - no?** Note I am not interested in centering the elements in the popup, this is purely optional. I just want to have the selected option to be in the center.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks now with the problem in red:

[image: problem]

Here is the `.xml` I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/some_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="packagename"
tools:showIn="@layout/specific_activity_layout"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#FF9800">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="@array/spinner1entries"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:popupBackground="#FFB74D"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_layout_spinners"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:popupBackground="#FFB74D"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:popupBackground="#FFB74D"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `rounded_corners` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFB74D"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Comment: In the first spinner what happens when you change `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` ?. `android:gravity` seems fine but if not, then try changing to `android:gravity="center" and see the difference.

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` shrinks the spinner, but I'd like to have it edge-to-edge :(

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? it's hard to see whats going on with the layout with just a text description.

Comment: @DaveS just added it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511049/set-view-text-align-at-center-in-spinner-in-android

Comment: are you using custom adapters for spinner?

Comment: Does spinner1 use a different adapter from spinner2 and spinner3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try adding :
  `android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"` to the spinner.
- You can try to set the text style programatically after an item is selected from the spinner. Set an `setOnItemSelectedListener` and inside it set TextView to be centred.

  ```
  Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
          // Set the text style after item is selected.
          setSpinnerSelectedItemParams(spinner1, getActivity());
  }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      }
  });



  /**
   * Sets the spinner text style to a different one after one value has been chosen.
   * @param spinner Spinner currently in use
   */
  public void setSpinnerSelectedItemParams(Spinner spinner, Context context) {
      if (spinner.getChildCount() > 0){
          TextView tvSpinner = ((TextView) spinner.getChildAt(0));
          tvSpinner.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
          tvSpinner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
          params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
          tvSpinner.setLayoutParams(params);
      }
  }
  ```

  If you want the text before selecting it in centre as well, try setting a custom resource when creating the adapter.

  In Activity or Fragment:

  ```
  ArrayAdapter<String> yourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity, R.layout.default_spinner_adapter_view, yourDataToFillTheSpinner);
  ```

  "default_spinner_adapter_view.xml" file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- This is the view for each individual item of the spinner-->
  <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/tv_default_spinner"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
  ```

Comment: What about the default item? This way it will be inconsistent - if it works it will display it in the centre only after user selection, but the default item will still be stuck to the left.

Comment: @Phantomazi The way I get around doing it is by setting a custom resource  when creating the `ArrayAdapter`. Something like: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(activity, R.layout.spinner_adapter_picker_view_center, yourData);`. Let me try to include it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the dropdown list items you will need to create a new layout file. Let’s call it spinner_dropdown_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

Another change in the declaration of the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom list item of spinner and set as you want and that should have a TextView id text1 and use this list_item.xml like below

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

> // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
>   layout

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.your_list_item);
```

> // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.your_drop_down_list_item);
```

> // Apply the adapter to the spinner

```
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

change relative layout to linear layout vertical and width of the spinner should be match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all spinners are using the same type of adapter—or at least another adapter using the same item layout—the adapter provides the layout.